# How to enable Oauth authentication only in API controllers in ASP .NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2

I have one ASP .NET MVC application. It is having both MVC controllers and API controllers. I am using OAUTH 2 for authentication. When i enable OAUTH authentication, it shows authorization error for normal controller action also.

The code i am using for registering authentication.

```
app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        AppStart(config);
        SwaggerConfig.Register(config);
        HttpServer server = new HttpServer(config);
        // Accepts OAuth Service v1.0 tokens
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(IdentifierUrl))
        {
            app.Map(
                new PathString("/v1"),
                p =>
                {
                    // Map to use OAuth 1 tokens            
                    p.UseEsoAccessTokenValidation(new EsoAccessTokenOptions { AuthorizationServerUrl = AuthorizationServer, Audiences = IdentifierUrl.Split(',') });
                    p.UseWebApi(server);
                });
        }

        // Accepts OAuth Service v2.0 tokens
        //app.Map("/v2", v2app =>
        //{
        app.UseEsoAccessTokenValidation(new EsoAccessTokenOptions
        {
            AuthorizationServerUrl = AuthorizationServer,
            Scopes = Scopes.Split(',')
        });
```

This is the error i am getting for each and every urls.

[image: error page]

Comment: Got any resolution? i getting this error on Web server for deployed site.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest doing the following.

**If you want authorization on:**

```
[Authorize]
public class AdminController : Controller
{
  //Action methods here
}
```

**If you want to disable it:**

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public class AdminController : Controller
    {
      //Action methods here
    }
```

**EDITED**

So as you mention you're having issues accesing the root...

There are a few things you can try!

**1. Change the portnumber**

Project properties > Web

[image]

**2. Delete .vs hidden folder**

1. Go to your project folder and open .vs folder (keep your check hidden item-box checked as this folder may be hidden sometimes)
2. in the .vs folder - open config
3. see that applicationhost config file there? Delete that thing.(Do not worry it will regenerate automatically once you recompile the project.)

**3. Or try create a new virtual directory**

Project properties > Web > Create Virtual Directory worked for me

Comment: But from the root url itself i am getting this error. i mean http://localhost:4567